# Reasoning for Stomatal Distribution Between Monocot and Dicot

Tags: plant-physiology

When you compare the stomatal arrangement of bean and corn plants under a microscope, you notice that the corn's stomata arrangement is much more organized and linear then the beans. I am wondering whether there is an evolutionary explanation for why that developed?

One thing to note is that the morphologies of the epithelial tissue cells are very different, so maybe it is a natural consequence of that?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a natural result of the differences in veining in the leaves?  The parallel veins in the corn leaf would constrain the placement of the stomata to the rather linear area between the veins.

Comment: Sounds plausible, can you provide some reference?